# Sublime Text 3 incorrect indentation when bringing in gists

Tags: sublimetext3

I have a few gists set up on github that I bring into sublime text 3 using package control's insert gist function.

When I bring my gists into sublime text 2 they are formatted correctly, yet with sublime text 3 the tab indentation is wrong when they come in.

This is how the gist is formatted on github:

```
.ir {
     border: 0;
     font: 0/0 a;
     text-shadow: none;
     color: transparent;
     background-color: transparent;
}
```

result after bringing the gist into Sublime Text 3:

```
.ir {
  border: 0;
    font: 0/0 a;
      text-shadow: none;
       color: transparent;
        background-color: transparent;
        }
```

I'm not sure why the extra spacing is getting added onto each line or how to remove it. I've tried turning automatic tab detection off already but that didn't help. Any assistance in solving this quirky formatting issue would be most appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Could have something to do with how the plugin works. There was probably some refactoring to make it ST3 compatible. I'd recommend creating an issue on the plugin page. Additionally, you may want to include the plugin you are using in your question.

Comment: The plugin I'm using is called "Gists" and I installed it via Sublime Text 2's package control plugin. I'll post this issue over on the plugin page also.

Thank you.

Edit: I see now that this is a common problem and the developer has been notified over on Github.

Comment: Was wondering if I could fix it but I don't see any package named `Gists`, only this: https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Gist but it's purpose is completely different

Comment: This is driving me nuts too - here's what I posted in the GitHub issues (hope it's not a duplicate!) https://github.com/condemil/Gist/issues/124

Answer (score 0):

you can define a shortcut to fix automatically.

I use the following keymap

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+r"], "command": "reindent" , "args": { "single_line": false } }
```